# How is cout special treatment of char * helpful?

Tags: c++, pointers

I just learned that `cout` has a 'helpful' feature when working with char pointers. So if we pass it a char pointer, `cout` will keep printing until it hits a null character. My question is, isn't this functionality more of a stumbling block when I want to do something special, say, use a `char` array to hold really small `int` values?

```
//pointers and strings
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char ch_arr [] = "Can you print this?";
    char *ptr_chr = ch_arr;
    char char_as_int[] = {1, 4, 5};
    int int_arr [] = {1, 2, 3};

    cout << ch_arr << endl;
    cout << ptr_chr << endl;
    cout << int_arr << endl;
    cout << char_as_int << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces (needed an image because weird characters won't copy):

[image: Helpful cout?]

In the program above, I was thinking I would be getting the start address of the array, but instead I got these funny characters. Please comment on this behavior of my compiler.

Comment: When you print the `char_as_int` array, the [overloaded `operator<<` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) which handles `char*` tries to print it as a string, using the numbers in the array as characters, and looking for a string terminator. Since you don't have a string terminator in the array you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know why this is happening. My question is, as I've written in the post, that this confuses me unnecessarily.

Comment: A character array is a character array, there's no way for `operator<<` to know that you really have an array of small integers. If you use `<<` to print an array of `char` or a pointer to `char`, it *will* be treated as a string.

Comment: As has been said, outputting a character array as a string is the most generally useful thing. You can easily output the address by casting it e.g. `cout << (void*)char_as_int << endl;` to avoid the char* overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> isn't this functionality more of a stumbling block when I want to do something special, say, use a char array to hold really small int values?

Yes, it can be. But only if you want to print the address or the value and don't realize that `char` is treated differently. You can still print the address by converting the pointer to `void*` and you can print the value by converting it to a larger integer type.

But it is very convenient when you do something typical like use the `char` array as a null terminated string.

Convenience in typical case beats convenience in special case.

Comment: To be fair, you also asked to comment on the behaviour of the compiler and people answered that.

Answer (score 1):

Character arrays ending in `NULL` are generally viewed as "string" (not to be confused with `std::string`).

What you are seeing is the console trying to print what are essentially unprintable characters since you try to `cout` content that is not printable (the integral values 1, 4, 5 etc).

The hex value (`0x7...`) is the pointer to the memory location of the `int` array. This is tied to functionality unrelated to character arrays.

As so to the

> ...doesn't this unnecessarily prevent me from using a char array for small ints...

And

> ... doesn't this unnecessarily prevent me from using a char array for small ints?

Well, that depends. In general no it doesn't. If you are modelling integers with a limited range as `char`s (e.g. such as byte arrays), then I imagine it may. Given the special use case, some extra work is generally required (or the use of an appropriate library).

Comment: thanks, but my question is, doesn't this unnecessarily prevent me from using a char array for small ints?

Comment: It prevents you from easily outputting the address of the start of the array, but that's a pretty unusual use case. This particular overload won't impact your ability to use a char array for small ints for any 'normal' usage. Besides, static arrays aren't very C++-y.